# Date Time tostring() method return different value java

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime, tostring

I am using JodaTime API for date time calculation. Moreover, When I am printing simply only DateTime on the console; it is printing correctly. But when I am using .toString() method; it is worng; date is changing.

This is the code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


        int[] startHour= {11, 0}; 
        int[] endtHour= {13, 0};
        DateTimeZone dtZoneforUser = DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York");
        DateTime dtNow = DateTime.now(dtZoneforUser);

        DateTime dtTimeWindowStart = new DateTime(dtNow.getYear(),dtNow.getMonthOfYear(),dtNow.dayOfMonth().get(),startHour[0],startHour[1],dtZoneforUser);
        DateTime dtTimeWindowEnd = new DateTime(dtNow.getYear(),dtNow.getMonthOfYear(),dtNow.dayOfMonth().get(),endtHour[0],endtHour[1],dtZoneforUser);

        List<String> lstAudio  = new ArrayList<String>();
        lstAudio.add("1");
        lstAudio.add("2");
        lstAudio.add("3");
        lstAudio.add("4");
        lstAudio.add("5");
        lstAudio.add("6");
        lstAudio.add("7");
        lstAudio.add("8");
        lstAudio.add("9");
        lstAudio.add("10");
        lstAudio.add("11");
        lstAudio.add("12");
        lstAudio.add("13");

        List<String> lstOfTimeToPlay = new ArrayList<String>();
        int[] randomNumber = { 46, 71, 41, 68, 58, 104, 47, 76, 46, 38, 71, 42, 52 };
        DateTime recurringStartingTime = dtTimeWindowStart;
        DateTime recurringEndTime = dtTimeWindowEnd;
        List<String> timeToPlay = new ArrayList<String>();
        int daysCounter = 0;
        String pattern1 = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern1).withZone(dtZoneforUser);

        for (int j = 0; j< 13; j++) {
            int randomNum = randomNumber[j]; 

            DateTime tempTime = recurringStartingTime.plusMinutes(randomNum);
            recurringStartingTime = tempTime;

            System.out.println(randomNum);

            if ( tempTime.isBefore(recurringEndTime) )
                {
                    System.out.println("Audio Id is "+j + " and the play time is "+tempTime);
                lstOfTimeToPlay.add(tempTime.withZone(dtZoneforUser).toString());
                }else {
                    daysCounter +=1;
                    recurringStartingTime = dtTimeWindowStart.plusDays(daysCounter).plusMinutes(randomNum);
                    recurringEndTime = dtTimeWindowEnd.plusDays(daysCounter); 
                    System.out.println("Audio Id is "+j + " and the play time is "+recurringStartingTime);
                    lstOfTimeToPlay.add(tempTime.withZone(dtZoneforUser).toString());
                }

        }

        for (String string : lstOfTimeToPlay) {
        System.out.println(string); 
        }
```

**The output is -
This is correct o/p.**

```
Audio Id is 0 and the play time is 2014-01-16T11:46:00.000-05:00
Audio Id is 1 and the play time is 2014-01-16T12:57:00.000-05:00
Audio Id is 2 and the play time is 2014-01-17T11:41:00.000-05:00
Audio Id is 3 and the play time is 2014-01-17T12:49:00.000-05:00
Audio Id is 4 and the play time is 2014-01-18T11:58:00.000-05:00
Audio Id is 5 and the play time is 2014-01-19T12:44:00.000-05:00
Audio Id is 6 and the play time is 2014-01-20T11:47:00.000-05:00
Audio Id is 7 and the play time is 2014-01-21T12:16:00.000-05:00
Audio Id is 8 and the play time is 2014-01-22T11:46:00.000-05:00
Audio Id is 9 and the play time is 2014-01-22T12:24:00.000-05:00
Audio Id is 10 and the play time is 2014-01-23T12:11:00.000-05:00
Audio Id is 11 and the play time is 2014-01-23T12:53:00.000-05:00
Audio Id is 12 and the play time is 2014-01-24T11:52:00.000-05:00

**This is List output (toString method() called )**
2014-01-16T11:46:00.000-05:00
2014-01-16T12:57:00.000-05:00
2014-01-16T13:38:00.000-05:00
2014-01-17T12:49:00.000-05:00
2014-01-17T13:47:00.000-05:00
2014-01-18T13:42:00.000-05:00
2014-01-19T13:31:00.000-05:00
2014-01-20T13:03:00.000-05:00
2014-01-21T13:02:00.000-05:00
2014-01-22T12:24:00.000-05:00
2014-01-22T13:35:00.000-05:00
2014-01-23T12:53:00.000-05:00
2014-01-23T13:45:00.000-05:00
```

In this above list there are three occurrences on 16 January that should be only two as per above list. Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: 2014-01-17T11:41:00.000-05:00 && 2014-01-16T13:38:00.000-05:00.
Time is different?

Comment: Didn't you want between 11 and 13. You appear to have times after 13:00.

Comment: @VinayakPingale Yes; that difference is coming; but first list is correct and then same list I am storing as a toString() ; but changing the value; Why??

Comment: @PeterLawrey I want between 11-13 hours but as per the random number; third date should come on 17 January not 16 January. It is coming after 13 hours. I think toString() is doing some miracle inside.???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you spot the difference?

Your code:

```
System.out.println("Audio Id is "+j + " and the play time is "+recurringStartingTime);
lstOfTimeToPlay.add(tempTime.withZone(dtZoneforUser).toString());
```

What you probably meant:

```
System.out.println("Audio Id is "+j + " and the play time is "+recurringStartingTime);
lstOfTimeToPlay.add(recurringStartingTime.withZone(dtZoneforUser).toString());
```

Comment: if this is the mistake then :(. Sad

Comment: OMG.................Thanks assylias. I am really thanksful to you...Thank U so much..............